# Select all records, join with table A if join exists, table B if not

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

So here's my scenario:

I'm working on Localization for a project of mine, and typically I would go about doing this in the C# code, however I want to do this in SQL a bit more since I am trying to buff up my SQL a bit.

Environment: SQL Server 2014 Standard, C# (.NET 4.5.1)

Note: the programming language itself should be irrelevant, I'm only including it for completeness.

So I sort-of accomplished what I wanted, but not to the extent I wanted. It's been a while (at least a year) since I have done any SQL `JOIN`s except basic ones, and this is quite a complex `JOIN`.

Here is a diagramme of the relevant tables of the database. (There are plenty more, but not necessary for this portion.)

[image: Database Diagramme]

All relationships described in the image are complete in the database - the `PK` and `FK` constraints are all setup and operating. None of the columns described are `null`able. All the tables have the schema `dbo`.

Now, I have a query which **almost** does what I want: that is, given *ANY* Id of `SupportCategories` and *ANY* Id of `Languages`, it will return either:

If there is a right-proper translation for that language for that string (I.e. `StringKeyId` -> `StringKeys.Id` exists, and in `LanguageStringTranslations` `StringKeyId`, `LanguageId`, and `StringTranslationId` combination exists, then it loads `StringTranslations.Text` for that `StringTranslationId`.

If the `LanguageStringTranslations` `StringKeyId`, `LanguageId`, and `StringTranslationId` combination did **NOT** exist, then it loads the `StringKeys.Name` value. The `Languages.Id` is a given `integer`.

My query, be it a mess, is as follows:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN T.x IS NOT NULL THEN T.x ELSE (SELECT
    CASE WHEN dbo.StringTranslations.Text IS NULL THEN dbo.StringKeys.Name ELSE dbo.StringTranslations.Text END AS Result
FROM dbo.SupportCategories
    INNER JOIN dbo.StringKeys
        ON dbo.SupportCategories.StringKeyId = dbo.StringKeys.Id
    INNER JOIN dbo.LanguageStringTranslations
        ON dbo.StringKeys.Id = dbo.LanguageStringTranslations.StringKeyId
    INNER JOIN dbo.StringTranslations
        ON dbo.StringTranslations.Id = dbo.LanguageStringTranslations.StringTranslationId
WHERE dbo.LanguageStringTranslations.LanguageId = 38 AND dbo.SupportCategories.Id = 0) END AS Result FROM (SELECT (SELECT
    CASE WHEN dbo.StringTranslations.Text IS NULL THEN dbo.StringKeys.Name ELSE dbo.StringTranslations.Text END AS Result
FROM dbo.SupportCategories
    INNER JOIN dbo.StringKeys
        ON dbo.SupportCategories.StringKeyId = dbo.StringKeys.Id
    INNER JOIN dbo.LanguageStringTranslations
        ON dbo.StringKeys.Id = dbo.LanguageStringTranslations.StringKeyId
    INNER JOIN dbo.StringTranslations
        ON dbo.StringTranslations.Id = dbo.LanguageStringTranslations.StringTranslationId
WHERE dbo.LanguageStringTranslations.LanguageId = 5 AND dbo.SupportCategories.Id = 0) AS x) AS T
```

The problem is that it is not capable of providing me **ALL** of the `SupportCategories` and their respective `StringTranslations.Text` if it exists, **OR** their `StringKeys.Name` if it didn't exist. It is perfect at providing any one of them, but not at all. Basically, it's to enforce that if a language does not have a translation for a specific key, then the default is to use `StringKeys.Name` which is of `StringKeys.DefaultLanguageId` translation. (Ideally, it would not even do that, but instead load the translation for `StringKeys.DefaultLanguageId`, which I can do myself if pointed in the right direction for the rest of the query.)

I've spent a LOT of time on this, and I know if I were to just write it in C# (like I usually do) it would be done by now. I want to do this in SQL, and I'm having trouble getting the output I like.

The only caveat, is I want to limit the number of actual queries applied. All columns are indexed and such as I like them for now, and without real stress-testing I cannot index them further.

Edit: Another note, I'm trying to keep the database as normalized as possible, so I don't want to duplicate things if I can avoid it.

### **Example Data**

**Source**

dbo.SupportCategories (Entirety):

```
Id  StringKeyId
0   0
1   1
2   2
```

dbo.Languages (185 records, only showing two for examples):

```
Id  Abbreviation    Family  Name    Native
38  en  Indo-European   English English
48  fr  Indo-European   French  français, langue française
```

dbo.LanguagesStringTranslations (Entirety):

```
StringKeyId LanguageId  StringTranslationId
0   38  0
1   38  1
2   38  2
3   38  3
4   38  4
5   38  5
6   38  6
7   38  7
1   48  8 -- added as example
```

dbo.StringKeys (Entirety):

```
Id  Name    DefaultLanguageId
0   Billing 38
1   API 38
2   Sales   38
3   Open    38
4   Waiting for Customer    38
5   Waiting for Support 38
6   Work in Progress    38
7   Completed   38
```

dbo.StringTranslations (Entirety):

```
Id  Text
0   Billing
1   API
2   Sales
3   Open
4   Waiting for Customer
5   Waiting for Support
6   Work in Progress
7   Completed
8   Les APIs -- added as example
```

**Current Output**

Given the exact query below, it outputs:

```
Result
Billing
```

**Desired Output**

Ideally, I would like to be able to omit the specific `SupportCategories.Id`, and get all of them, as so (regardless if language 38 `English` was used, or 48 `French`, or *ANY* other language at the moment):

```
Id  Result
0   Billing
1   API
2   Sales
```

**Additional Example**

Given I were to add a localization for `French` (I.e. add `1 48 8` to `LanguageStringTranslations`), the output would change to (note: this is example only, obviously I would add a localized string to `StringTranslations`) (updated with French example):

```
Result
Les APIs
```

**Additional Desired Output**

Given the example above, the following output would be desired (updated with French example):

```
Id  Result
0   Billing
1   Les APIs
2   Sales
```

(Yes, I know technically that's wrong from a consistency standpoint, but it's what would be desired in the situation.)

### Edit:

Small updated, I did change the structure of the `dbo.Languages` table, and drop the `Id (int)` column from it, and replace it with `Abbreviation` (which is now renamed to `Id`, and all relative Foreign-Keys and and relationships updated). From a technical standpoint, this is a more appropriate setup in my opinion due to the fact that the table is limited to ISO 639-1 codes, which are unique to begin with.

### **Tl;dr**

So: the question, how could I modify this query to return *everything* from `SupportCategories` and then return either `StringTranslations.Text` for that `StringKeys.Id`, `Languages.Id` combination, *or* the `StringKeys.Name` if it did **NOT** exist?

My initial thought, is that I could somehow cast the current query to another temporary type as another subquery, and wrap this query in yet another `SELECT` statement and select the two fields I want (`SupportCategories.Id` and `Result`).

If I don't find anything, I'll just do the standard method I typically use which is to load all the `SupportCategories` into my C# project, and then with it run the query I have above manually against each `SupportCategories.Id`.

Thanks for any and all suggestions/comments/critique.

Also, I apologize for it being absurdly long, I just don't want any ambiguity. I'm often on StackOverflow and see questions that lack substance, didn't wish to make that mistake here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the first approach I came up with:

```
DECLARE @ChosenLanguage INT = 48;

SELECT sc.Id, Result = MAX(COALESCE(
   CASE WHEN lst.LanguageId = @ChosenLanguage      THEN st.Text END,
   CASE WHEN lst.LanguageId = sk.DefaultLanguageId THEN st.Text END)
)
FROM dbo.SupportCategories AS sc
INNER JOIN dbo.StringKeys AS sk
  ON sc.StringKeyId = sk.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.LanguageStringTranslations AS lst
  ON sk.Id = lst.StringKeyId
  AND lst.LanguageId IN (sk.DefaultLanguageId, @ChosenLanguage)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.StringTranslations AS st
  ON st.Id = lst.StringTranslationId
  --WHERE sc.Id = 1
  GROUP BY sc.Id
  ORDER BY sc.Id;
```

Basically, get the potential strings that match the chosen language *and* get all the default strings, then aggregate so you only pick one per `Id` - prioritize on the chosen language, then take the default as a fallback.

You can probably do similar things with `UNION`/`EXCEPT` but I suspect this will almost always lead to multiple scans against the same objects.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative solution that avoids the `IN` and the grouping in Aaron's answer:

```
DECLARE 
    @SelectedLanguageId integer = 48;

SELECT 
    SC.Id,
    SC.StringKeyId,
    Result =
        CASE
            -- No localization available
            WHEN LST.StringTranslationId IS NULL
            THEN SK.Name
            ELSE
            (
                -- Localized string
                SELECT ST.[Text]
                FROM dbo.StringTranslations AS ST
                WHERE ST.Id = LST.StringTranslationId
            )
        END
FROM dbo.SupportCategories AS SC
JOIN dbo.StringKeys AS SK
    ON SK.Id = SC.StringKeyId
LEFT JOIN dbo.LanguageStringTranslations AS LST
    WITH (FORCESEEK) -- Only for low row count in sample data
    ON LST.StringKeyId = SK.Id
    AND LST.LanguageId = @SelectedLanguageId;
```

As noted, the `FORCESEEK` hint is only required to get the most efficient-looking plan due to the low cardinality of the `LanguageStringTranslations` table with the sample data provided. With more rows, the optimizer will choose an index seek naturally.

The execution plan itself has an interesting feature:

[image: Execution Plan]

The Pass Through property on the last outer join means that a lookup to the `StringTranslations` table is only performed if a row was previously found in the `LanguageStringTranslations` table. Otherwise, the inner side of this join is skipped completely for the current row.

#### Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Languages
(
    Id integer NOT NULL,
    Abbreviation char(2) NOT NULL,
    Family nvarchar(96) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(96) NOT NULL,
    [Native] nvarchar(96) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_Languages
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.StringTranslations
(
    Id bigint NOT NULL,
    [Text] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_StringTranslations
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.StringKeys
(
    Id bigint NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    DefaultLanguageId integer NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_StringKeys
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),

    CONSTRAINT FK_dbo_StringKeys_DefaultLanguageId
    FOREIGN KEY (DefaultLanguageId)
    REFERENCES dbo.Languages (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.SupportCategories
(
    Id integer NOT NULL,
    StringKeyId bigint NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_SupportCategories
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),

    CONSTRAINT FK_dbo_SupportCategories
    FOREIGN KEY (StringKeyId)
    REFERENCES dbo.StringKeys (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.LanguageStringTranslations
(
    StringKeyId bigint NOT NULL,
    LanguageId integer NOT NULL,
    StringTranslationId bigint NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_LanguageStringTranslations
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (StringKeyId, LanguageId, StringTranslationId),

    CONSTRAINT FK_dbo_LanguageStringTranslations_StringKeyId
    FOREIGN KEY (StringKeyId)
    REFERENCES dbo.StringKeys (Id),

    CONSTRAINT FK_dbo_LanguageStringTranslations_LanguageId
    FOREIGN KEY (LanguageId)
    REFERENCES dbo.Languages (Id),

    CONSTRAINT FK_dbo_LanguageStringTranslations_StringTranslationId
    FOREIGN KEY (StringTranslationId)
    REFERENCES dbo.StringTranslations (Id)
);
```

#### Sample Data

```
INSERT dbo.Languages
    (Id, Abbreviation, Family, Name, [Native])
VALUES
    (38, 'en', N'Indo-European', N'English', N'English'),
    (48, 'fr', N'Indo-European', N'French', N'français, langue française');

INSERT dbo.StringTranslations
    (Id, [Text])
VALUES
    (0, N'Billing'),
    (1, N'API'),
    (2, N'Sales'),
    (3, N'Open'),
    (4, N'Waiting for Customer'),
    (5, N'Waiting for Support'),
    (6, N'Work in Progress'),
    (7, N'Completed'),
    (8, N'Les APIs'); -- added as example

INSERT dbo.StringKeys
    (Id, Name, DefaultLanguageId)
VALUES
    (0, 'Billing', 38),
    (1, 'API', 38),
    (2, 'Sales', 38),
    (3, 'Open', 38),
    (4, 'Waiting for Customer', 38),
    (5, 'Waiting for Support', 38),
    (6, 'Work in Progress', 38),
    (7, 'Completed', 38);

INSERT dbo.SupportCategories
    (Id, StringKeyId)
VALUES
    (0, 0),
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2);

INSERT dbo.LanguageStringTranslations
    (StringKeyId, LanguageId, StringTranslationId)
VALUES
    (0, 38, 0),
    (1, 38, 1),
    (2, 38, 2),
    (3, 38, 3),
    (4, 38, 4),
    (5, 38, 5),
    (6, 38, 6),
    (7, 38, 7),
    (1, 48, 8); -- added as example
```